# to read a particular windows security log

Tags: c#, .net

how do i read a particular windows security log(ex. lock event) in a console. i need the events for the present day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should know name of source (this is a column in Event Viewer and usually is the name of application which wrote event log information).

Add System.Diagnostics namespace reference to your code file:

```
using System.Diagnostics
```

Then you have to create an instance of EventLog.

```
// First, check if event log contains required source
if(EventLog.SourceExists("YourSourceName"))
{
    // Specify your source name and log name (e.g. Application, System or some custom name)
    EventLog log = new EventLog()
    {
        Source = "YourSourceName",
        Log = "Application"
    };

    // Enumerate through log entries
    foreach (EventLogEntry entry in log.Entries)
    {
        // Do something with log entries
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Message);
    }

     // You also may filter log entries by date (LINQ is used for this)
     foreach (EventLogEntry entry in log.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().Where(x => (DateTime.Now - x.TimeGenerated).Days == 0))
    {
        // Do something with log entries
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Message);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.